# EsLint: Parsing error: Invalid value for lib provided: es2021

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint

I tried to implement eslint in one of my [React/TypeScript project](https://gitlab.com/johannchopin/my-cv). I created my `.eslintrc.js` using eslint's cli `yarn eslint --init` with the airbnb config:

```js
module.exports = {
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "airbnb"
    ],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 12,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "rules": {
    }
};
```

But when I run eslint, I get this error for all of my `.tsx` files:

> 0:0 error  Parsing error: Invalid value for lib provided: es2021

All my files start with the import of React:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
...
```

As someone an idea of what the issue is?

Comment: I suspect you're going to run into a massive number of incompatible the rules if you use the entire AirBnB ruleset. It is was not specified with Typescript in mind.

Answer (score 5):

In your archive .eslintrc.js, change the "parseOption" to:

```
"parserOptions": {
  ...,
  "ecmaVersion": 2020
},
```