# Eslint - Parsing error: Invalid value for lib provided: es2022

Tags: angular, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint, typescript-eslintparser

I wanted to use [`Array.prototype.at()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at) from es2022 but typescript told me I should set the lib property of the tsconfig to es2022 if I wanted to use it. I did and it works and it compiles.

However, now eslint is giving me an error at the top of every TS files.

> Parsing error: Invalid value for lib provided: es2022eslint

I found surprisingly very little information about that error on the net. I saw similar questions asked [there](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/2468) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63742410/eslint-parsing-error-invalid-value-for-lib-provided-es2021) but that didn't helped me.

Here is my tsconfig:

```json
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "strict": true,
        "strictNullChecks": false,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "target": "es2020",
        "module": "es2020",
        "lib": ["es2022", "dom"],
        "paths": {
            "@app/*": ["src/app/*"],
            "@env/*": ["src/environments/*"]
        }
    },
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
        "strictInjectionParameters": true,
        "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
        "strictTemplates": true
    }
}
```

Here is the relevant part of my .eslintrc.json:

```json
"parserOptions": {
    "project": ["tsconfig.json", "e2e/tsconfig.json"],
    "createDefaultProgram": true,
    "ecmaVersion": "latest"
},
```

I tried to set `ecmaVersion` to 2021, 2022 and latest but that error keeps poping.

Is there a way to tell eslint to ignore that error ? or disable that check ? The project compiles fine.

Comment: Within your tsconfig.json file what are your target, module, and lib properties?

Answer (score 4):

Check your @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin version.
If your typescript version is newer than @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin shows that error.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by explicitly instructing ESLint to use `@typescript-eslint/parser`: in your `.eslintrc.json` add

```
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
```

at the top level. (This is assuming you already have the necessary typescript-eslint packages in your project.)